# can't send mail to domain prefixed username

Tags: sles, active-directory, mailx

## How can I send mail to a local user with a domain prefixed username?

Running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11.3 joined to an active directory domain with Heirloom mailx version 12.5 7/5/10

### Scenario:

I have 2 users on the server, one local user account and one domain user account:

- jeff
- DOM1\john

Logged in as DOM1\john, I can issue this command from terminal `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" jeff` and jeff successfully receives the message. Not surprisingly, the header reads an escaped backslash in the `FROM` field `From: "DOM1\\john"@server.example.com`

Oddly, if jeff simply replies to the message, jeff will get an `Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender` in inbox. The header says `To: DOM1john@server.example.com`, so I can see that the backslash is getting stripped out. I have tried the following commands as jeff to attempt to escape the backslash, all to no avail, and the backslash is always omitted in the `TO` header of the undelivered message:

- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" DOM1\john`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" 'DOM1\john'`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" "DOM1\john"`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" DOM1\john@server.example.com`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" 'DOM1\john'@server.example.com`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" "DOM1\john"@server.example.com`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" DOM1\\john`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" 'DOM1\\john'`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" "DOM1\\john"`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" DOM1\\john@server.example.com`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" 'DOM1\\john'@server.example.com`
- `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" "DOM1\\john"@server.example.com`

Stranger still, if I try 3 backslashes, `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" DOM1\\\john`, it doesn't deliver the message nor issue an undelivered message, it just fails silently.

And if I try to just send the mail without the domain prefix, `echo "hello" | mail -s "test" john`, I get the expected undelivered message saying that user john doesn't exist.

Also, to be clear, yes these domain users have email accounts like john@dom1.example.com, but we don't want to send to that mail server account - we just want to use the local mail accounts on SLES so they can communicate with the other local non-domain accounts on that server.

Answer (score 0):

You gave in too easily. You saw the header

```
From: "DOM1\\john"@server.example.com
```

and that is what you need, but you must preserve the double-quotes and double backslash:

```
echo "hello" | mail -s "test" '"DOM1\\john"@server.example.com'
```

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part) on the local part of an email address:

> Space and `"(),:;<>@[\]` characters are allowed with restrictions (they are only allowed inside a quoted string, ... and in addition, a backslash ... must be preceded by a backslash).
>
> A quoted string may exist ... when the outermost quotes are the outermost characters of the local-part ... e.g. "abcdefghixyz"@example.com. Quoted strings and characters however, are not commonly used. RFC 5321 also warns that "a host that expects to receive mail SHOULD avoid defining mailboxes where the Local-part requires (or uses) the Quoted-string form".

Comment: I was so hopeful, but this one doesn't work either. It strips it out also...

Comment: Perhaps it is the mail command which is at fault. Try using sendmail directly: `echo "hello" | sendmail -v '"DOM1\\john"@server.example.com'`

Comment: so that command spits out `Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <jeff>.` and then when I look at the message, it says `<"DOM1\\john"@server.example.com>: delivery via local: delivered to mailbox` however, when I login as DOM1\john, and run `mail` I get `No mail for DOM1\john` so it says it's sent, but never received...

Comment: Try looking at root's mailbox or `/var/spool/mail/` for any failure mails. If you are really using sendmail you could possibly setup `/etc/aliases` (or `/etc/mail/aliases`) for each id, and its version without backslash, to the right spool file so that they have a version of their id that will work.